# xcopy is not recognized when variables are defined in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, set, xcopy

I am working on a batch file to copy some files from one folder to another. 
If I define the paths on the batch, the xcopy command won't work. If I do not define the variables the xcopy command works normally.

Example 1, this won't work:

```
@echo off
set pathA=C:\xx\kk
set pathB=C:\xx\mm
xcopy "%pathA%\*.doc" "%pathB%"
```

Example 2, this will work:

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\xx\kk\*.doc" "C:\xx\mm"
```

The paths I am working with, are very long and so I would like to define them as variables and avoid writing them each time I use them.

Do you guys know why xcopy does not work in the Example 1 and what can I do to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with removing `echo off` from your batch, and actually looking at what CMD is trying to tell you.  If you're still confused, edit your question to include the full output *without* the echo off line.

Comment: Works perfectly well for me.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply. "CMD msg is 'xcopy is not recognized as an internal or external command..." However, xcopy works properly if I avoid setting the paths as variables on the top of the batch. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do not manipulate the environment variable __PATH__, or at least do it right. You could also use `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe` instead of just `xcopy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was somehow the backslash when setting the variables. I have just set the variables as:

`set pathA=C:\xx\kk\
 set pathB=C:\xx\mm\`

and call xcopy as:

`xcopy "%pathA%*.doc" "%pathB%"  /S /E /Y`

Still no idea why, but now it works well!

Thanks again for your help!